# Display data from sql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a very simple PHP to search for a record in a field on MySQL database and return all details for that field.

Unfortunately, every time I enter the number to search for anything, nothing comes back, not even any errors.

My Code below:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("cant connect to db");
mysql_select_db("db name")or die("cant connect.....");
$output='';

//collect
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $searchq=$_POST['search'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE licence LIKE  '%$searchq%'") or die("cant search....");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count==0){
        $output='no results';
    } else {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $fdriver=$row['driver'];   
            $flicence=$row['licence']; 
            $fofficer=$row['officer'];
            $fspeed=$row['speed'];
            $ffine=$row['fine'];
            $fcategory=$row['category'];
            $output.='<div> '.$fdriver.' '.$flicence.' '.$fspeed.' '.$ffine.'  '.$fcategory.'</div>';
        }
    }
}

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Search</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h3>Search</h3>
        <p>You have to enter your number to search</p>
        <form method="post" action="search_start.php" >
            <input type="text" name="name">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
        </form>

        <?php print("$output"); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sidenote: Use `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` and get the real errors instead of what you're using now, should there be any.

Comment: sidenote: you are vulnerable to SQL-Injections, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with using prepared statements

Answer (score 1):

You're checking `$_POST['search']`, so the name of your text element field should be changed to search.

```
<input type="text" name="search">
```

Comment: unfortunately it still doesnt work. i get nothing back when i press search

Answer (score 1):

first change the name of your textbox to search

```
<input type="text" name="search">
```

second your query should be like this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE licence LIKE  '%".$searchq."%'");
```

Comment: I made the changes and unfortunately everytime i enter a licence and press search, nothing at all come up.

Comment: change your `if(isset($_POST['search'])){` to

  `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {`

Comment: same thing. infact when i edit like this then the search portion of form dissapears and i get left with a blank page

Comment: strange, are you sure that there are no typos? licence might supposed to be license. Add echos to debug to see which if/else statements it is reaching

Comment: nope no typos. i spelt licence like that. I am totally new at this so how would i add echos to debug. i have followed tutorials to get this far

Comment: try to echo this $_POST['search']; to see if you receive your inputted value

Comment: are they in seperated file? the php and form? if not your action is wrong, input this instead

`action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"`

Comment: the php and form are in the same so i added action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" but the funny thing is that as soon as i add echo, the form also dissapears and the page is shown blank. funny why that happens because i seriously cant find any issues. its quite a simple wrtiten code